# Why when $\gcd(r, 60) = 1$ and $60∣r(x−y)$, we have $60∣(x−y)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

In my math book it says:

"*This means that $60 \mid r(x - y)$. But, since $\gcd(r, 60) = 1$, we know that $60 \mid (x - y)$.*"

I would like to know why when gcd(r, 60) = 1, we can say that $60 \mid r(x - y)$ is equal to $60 \mid (x - y)$. It must be simple, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: That is what we call Euclid's Lemma.  If $a|bc$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then $a|c$.

Comment: Don' say that $60|r(x-y)$ is equal to $60|(x-y)$. It should be  $60|r(x-y)$ implies $60|(x-y)$

Comment: Yes, I will keep in mind. Or maybe like the book say "we know that..."? I'm googling for Euclid's Lemma, see if I can make some more of it.

Comment: The x -y is a red herring.  Let $x-y =b$.  Then $\gcd(60,r) = 1$ means $60$ and $r$ have no factors in common. If $60|rb$ then all the factors of 60 are factors of $r$ and $b$.  But $60$ and $r$ have no factors in common.  So the factors are only factors of $b$ and $60|b$.

Comment: @fleablood Yes, it is really clear now! Thanks :-)

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan Thanks for heading me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To provide a very simple and intuitive explanation of the Euclid's lemma in this case: if $60 \mid r(x - y) \,\,$, then all prime factors of $60$ must be included in those of $r(x - y)\,$. On the other hand, if the gcd of $60$ and $r $ is $1$, they have no common prime factors. So all prime factors of $60$ must be included in those of $x - y \,$, and then $60 \mid (x - y)\,\,$.

Comment: Thank you, this cleared it up really, really greatly :-) !